# Batch: Compare File Sizes

Tags: file, batch-file, compare, dos

I have seen a few different ways to compare files, using COMP, FC and a few others, but what I need to do is a basic file size compare, and then do a local copy of the file if it is larger, to the network file.

The files could be anything from 200kb and 5gb.  So I am really only interested in the file size and not content.

I would prefer a basic Dos script to run through a login script.

```
Check local file A
Check remote file B
If file A is bigger than file B
  Copy B to A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOR loop expansion `z` will return the size of a file (e.g. `%~zl`).
Delayed variable expansion is a requirement for this script. This particular script only copies if the file is larger, but you could easily change it to copy the file if the size is at all different by changing `GTR` to `NEQ`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET REMOTE_DIR=\\SERVER\share\path\to\files
SET LOCAL_DIR=.

FOR /F %%f IN (files_to_compare.txt) DO (
    SET "REMOTE_FILE=%REMOTE_DIR%\%%~nxf"
    SET "LOCAL_FILE=%LOCAL_DIR%\%%~nxf"
    FOR %%r IN (!REMOTE_FILE!) DO (
        @ECHO [REMOTE] %%~nxr: %%~zr
        FOR %%l IN (!LOCAL_FILE!) DO (
            @ECHO [LOCAL] %%~nxl: %%~zl
            IF %%~zr GTR %%~zl (
                @ECHO %%~nxr: Remote file IS larger [%%~zr] ^> [%%~zl]
                COPY /Y "%%~r" "%%~l"
            ) ELSE (
                @ECHO %%~nxr: Remote file is not larger [%%~zr] ^<= [%%~zl]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I had to fettle it a little as I wanted the local file to have precedence and also as you suggested, NEQ worked better for my needs.

Comment: this won't work file files larger than 2GB due to limitation in cmd math, hence won't fork for OP's 5GB files

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, for that, there's PowerShell. `powershell -noprofile -command "If ( (get-item -path !REMOTE_FILE! -force).length -ne (get-item -path !LOCAL_FILE! -force).length) { Exit 1 } Else { Exit 0 }" <NUL` The exit code of that command (!ERRORLEVEL!) can be used in the if statement.

Comment: The `-force` is probably not necessary. I had to add it to test against the largest files on my system, pagefile.sys and hiberfill.sys, both of which are hidden/system files.

Comment: There is an error on the answer. The code checks `If file B is bigger than file A` and not as requested by the question `If file A is bigger than file B`

Comment: @Einstein1969 You're correct about a discrepancy between the script and the OP (although I even pointed that out in the answer). The script is very clear about which file is bigger (local vs remote) and could easily be adapted to whichever scenario a person wanted. Since I wasn't contracted to write the script, I wrote what *I* would have wanted. I still can't think of any reasons why I would want to replace a larger file with a smaller file.