# Batch: Comparing filesize and overwriting if new file is smaller

Tags: batch-file, copy, special-characters, overwrite, filesize

I have 2 folders containing the same filenames. I want to copy files from one folder to the other only if it's filesize is smaller. I'm using a batch file adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741022/2690062). Here's the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET REMOTE_DIR=%~dp0iter1\
SET LOCAL_DIR=.

FOR %%f IN (*.7z) DO (
    SET "REMOTE_FILE=%REMOTE_DIR%\%%~nxf"
    SET "LOCAL_FILE=%LOCAL_DIR%\%%~nxf"
    FOR %%r IN ("!REMOTE_FILE!") DO (
        @ECHO [REMOTE] %%~nxr: %%~zr
        FOR %%l IN ("!LOCAL_FILE!") DO (
            @ECHO [LOCAL] %%~nxl: %%~zl
            IF %%~zr GTR %%~zl (
                @ECHO %%~nxr: New file is larger, not copying. [%%~zr] ^> [%%~zl]
            ) ELSE (
                @ECHO %%~nxr: New file is smaller, copying. [%%~zr] ^<= [%%~zl]
                COPY /Y "%%~r" "%%~l"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My problem currently is that filenames with an exclamation mark don't work with the script. I get a `File not found` after `COPY /Y "%%~r" "%%~l"` and `@ECHO %%~nxr` returns the filename with the exclamation removed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: SET variables under delayed expansion DISABLED and USE them with delayed expansion ENABLED

Comment: Do not use delayed expansion, it is not needed. Change `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, ```SET REMOTE_DIR=%~dp0iter1\```, to `SET "REMOTE_DIR=%~dp0iter1"`, `SET LOCAL_DIR=.` to `SET "LOCAL_DIR=."`. Then delete the lines containing `SET "REMOTE_FILE=%REMOTE_DIR%\%%~nxf"`, and `SET "LOCAL_FILE=%LOCAL_DIR%\%%~nxf"`. And finally change `!REMOTE_FILE!` to `%REMOTE_DIR%\%%~nxf` and `!LOCAL_FILE!` to `%LOCAL_DIR%\%%~nxf`.